# Find where solution is unique using Method of Characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

Find (in implicit form) the solution $u(x, y)$ of the equation:
$$u_x+uu_y=x$$

when $$u(0, y) = 1 + \sin y \qquad \text{for} \qquad y > 0 $$
Show that your solution is uniquely determined in the region $( −1 < x < 1,\, y_L(x)\leqslant y < ∞)$ where $y_L(x)$ is a function you should find. Show
that $u_y$ becomes unbounded as x → ±1 for certain values of y.

Working: 
I got the implicit form: 
$$(t, \frac{t^3}{6}+(\sin{s}+1)t +s, \frac{t^2}{2}+\sin{s}+1)$$
Then I calculated the Jacobian, $J\frac{(x,y)}{(s,t)}$ and got:
$$J= -t\cos{s}-1$$
So J=0 when $t=-1/\cos{s}$
So then I got that, since $x=t$, for $$-1\leqslant x\leqslant1$$ we get $$ \qquad J\ne0$$

But now I'm not sure how to find $y_L(x)$, and how to answer the part about $u_y$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You got correctly that
$$
dx=\frac{dy}z=\frac{dz}{x}
$$
so that $z=b+\frac12x^2$ and $y=a+bx+\frac16x^3=a+xz-\frac13x^3$. As $a,b$ are constants of the characteristic, and in the surface of the function $z=u(x,y)$ the characteristic curves form a one-parameter family, the constants are dependent on each other, for instance via $b=\phi(a)$. The solution is then implicitly given via 
$$
z-\frac12x^2=\phi(y-xz+\frac13x^3)\implies 1+\sin(y)=\phi(y)
$$
so that in total the solution is given via the implicit equation
$$
u(x,y)=z=1+\frac12x^2+\sin(y-xz+\frac13x^3).
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I was fine finding the implicit equation, my trouble came in finding where it is unique. Ie, as specified in the question, the lower bound of y in terms of x. Any ideas?